# Getting Excel to select from one of three range options

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to devise a dynamic spread sheet involving pension contribution percentages which increases with the age of the employees.
I've used the `=now()` function to calculate their ages on a dynamic basis and I now need to get excel to look at their age in cell H2 and apply the following criteria, altering automatically as their age increases into the next bracket:

- if they are currently aged between 18 - 39 pension contribution is 6%
- between 40 - 49 it is 7%
- and over 50 it is 10%

The formula I've devised is picking up the correct percentages for those 39 & under and for those 50+ but I can't get it to recognize the 7% for those between 40 - 49.

Can anybody tell me where I'm going wrong?

`=IF(H2>=OR18<=39,"6%",IF(H2>=OR40<=49,"7%",IF(H2>=OR50>100,"10%")))`

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled by the `OR` bit in the formula - if you have `OR18` Excel assumes it to be a cell reference o.O - no matter, I have suggested an answer that works

Comment: Great, glad it helped - if you can accept my answer I can get some much needed street cred!

Comment: Hi Raad - your solution worked perfectly! Do I need to post a comment anywhere else on the site in order for you to get the 'street cred' you deserved?

Comment: Hi Doug - just click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in, thanks.

Comment: don't forget to click the tick/check mark! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow!

So assuming the value to test is in cell `A1`, the basic formula for matching within a range (say 1-10) is:

`=IF(AND(A1 >= 1, A1 <= 10), "In Range", "Out of Range")`

So expanding this to 3 ranges (18-39, 40-49, and 50+), and substituting your percentages, we get:

`=IF(AND(A1 >= 18, A1 <= 39), "6%", IF(AND(A1 >= 40, A1 <= 49), "7%", IF(A1 >= 50, "10%")))`

So a loose end that needs tying up is what to do if the age is less than 18 - currently this formula will produce `FALSE`. You might want to put something else in by adding a result for the second condition in the last test - so where the value doesn't match >= 50, e.g.

`... IF(A1 >= 50, "10%", "NOT APPLICABLE") ...`

or some other value that's appropriate.

Comment: That's brilliant Raad, thank you so much. I don't need to worry about less than 18 as we don't employ anybody under that age